# R programming - if/else command

Tags: r

i am a new student of R programming since my current job has required that i become adapt to it.  I just started however, and as with anything the learning curve is steep.  My current project requires me to use the if/else or for command.  There are a set of numbers:

```
1.586077^+00
3.242631^-03
2.426304^-03
8.616781^-04
5.396826^-03
2.947846^-04
1.018943^+01
8.639457^-03
8.458051^-03
2.807870^+02
```

now I need a command which goes through these numbers and if the number is greater than 1, then it writes it down.  If the number is less than 1, then it adds it till it hits the next number greater than 1 and then writes the sum from the beginning to that point.  So for example:

Since the above set has 10 numbers, the output should like: `1, 2.138069469, 10.025406833`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you stuck? You'll get a better response if it looks like we aren't doing *everything* for you :)

Comment: i tried googling how to use if/else command, but the examples i found were not similar to what i needed.  And believe me, answer to this problem does not solve everything for me.  I wish it did, but it doesn't.  It's just part of a big problem and i just happen to be stuck here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `1.586077^+00` is 1.

Comment: yea youre right...it was my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- c(.5, 0.2, 2, 3.4, 0.4, 1.2, .2, .8, 2.3, 7.4)

result.final <- NULL
cumul.total <- 0

for (i in x) {

  cumul.total <- cumul.total + i

  if(i > 1){
    result <- cumul.total
  }

  else {
    next
  }

  result.final <- c(result.final, result)

}

result.final
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Harrison.  Most of this response makes sense to me and its almost perfect in getting what i need.  Maybe my question was unclear but, is there a way to add from the beginning to the point where where the number greater than 1 comes.

Comment: I think I'm confused now, the list of numbers you just gave me is the output of my script. Did you mean you want the cumulative sum? So 2.7, 6.1, etc?

Comment: I think I'm confused now, the list of numbers you just gave me is the output of my script. Did you mean you want the cumulative sum? So 2.7, 6.1, etc? – Harrison Jones 1 min ago - YES, EXACTLY

Comment: Alright see the new answer

Comment: Then you should use `cumsum(x)`

Comment: Can you use `cumsum(x)` with a condition?

Comment: @HarrisonJones `cumsum(x)[x >= 1]`

Comment: @SeñorO way easier than my method